# corrupted "/etc/ld.so.conf" file, how can I fix it?

Tags: libraries

I am trying to compile **Simple Screen Recorder** in this link https://github.com/MaartenBaert/ssr. I had linker error due to wrong  library path. While checking out library paths I noticed that I had corrupted `/etc/ld.so.conf` file, I have no idea how it happened but it turned out to be Chinese.

湩汣摵⁥支捴氯⹤潳挮湯⹦⽤⸪潣普ਊ甯牳氯捯污氯扩

甯牳氯捯污氯扩ਊ

Would anybody post default contents of it?

EDIT:

To my surprize I get correct paths with

```
$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf

include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf

/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/lib
```

And I get Chinese letters with

```
sudo gedit /etc/ld.so.conf
```

So, is it a **gedit** bug?

I read the content with

```
sudo leafpad /etc/ld.so.conf
```

again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
chick@dad:~$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It will fix **ld.so.conf** file.

Comment: I think I am victim of **gedit** bug. I updated my question